# Proof that $\sup (A^2) = (\sup A)^2$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\emptyset \ne A \subseteq \mathbb R$ be a set of non-negative numbers.  Also suppose $A$ is bounded above.  Define $A^2 = \{a^2 : a\in A\}$.  I want to prove that $\sup A^2 = (\sup A)^2$.  I've been approaching this by showing that $(\sup A)^2$ is an upper bound of $A^2$ and then showing that it's the least among the set of upper bounds.  That is to say, I've been approaching it from the definition of $\sup A^2$.

The first part is easy if we already know that $x \le y$ and $0\le z$ together imply $xz \le yz$.

So let's consider the second part, that if $y$ is any upper bound for $A^2$ then $(\sup A)^2 \le y$.  Here I'm quite stumped.  If we let $a\in A$ then we know $a^2 \le y$ and that $a\le \sup A$.  Of course we can also infer $a^2 \le (\sup A)^2$ but I don't see much gained from that.  I might want to refer to the square-root of $y$.  But I'm trying to prove this claim, in order to prove that the square-root is well-defined.  So that seems to risk circularity.

I've considered trying to argue by contradiction, so suppose $y < (\sup A)^2$.  From here it would be nice to try to find some quantity which is a smaller upper bound on $A$ than $\sup A$.  But I don't see a construction of such a number since, again, I'm avoiding the use of the square-root.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Let $ B $ a non empty subset of $\Bbb R$.

To prove that $ M=\sup B $, you just need to prove that $ M $ is an upper bound of $ B $ and that there exist a sequence $ (b_n)$ of elements in $ B $ which converge to $ M $.

Use the implication you might know
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}b_n=M\implies \lim_{n\to+\infty}b_n^2=M^2$$